# Why does saving this image into an SQLite database lower the quality so much?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I'm making a list app for wine where you can put in details and an image about wines that you enter and put the data into an SQLite database on the phone.

I just worked out getting the image into the database but it's very low quality, even though I have the quality integer set to 95 (out of 100).

Can anyone give tips on how to do this in a better way?

Here is the relevant info from the AddActivity:

```
btnAddPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
        }
    });

//this method happens after taking the image
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        toastMessage("Image has been taken successfully");

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, stream);
        imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

I then put that imageInByte variable into the database.

Comment: `Log.d` the dimensions of `Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");`, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink test 1 using the emulated device: width: 160, height: 120........ test 2 using my google pixel: width: 190, height: 253

Comment: ok so the Bitmap you are trying to `compress()` has 160 pixels in width and 120 pixels in height - is it what you are expecting?

Comment: how about reading the doc? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: Why would you ever save an image in the database?  Datbases are shitty for binary data.  Store it in a file, and if needed save the name of the file in the database.  Storing large amounts of binary data in a db like that just reduces the performance of the db.

Comment: @GabeSechan Storing smallish images in a DB [is perfectly fine](http://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html).

Comment: @cl no, ores a anti pattern that needs to die

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the image is such low quality is that it is actually getting the thumbnail version of the picture.

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

This doesn't retrieve the full image. If you want the full image, you need to use the EXTRA_OUTPUT extra to save the full image. Then, you can put the file path into the database to retrieve the full sized image.

For documentation on ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Hope this helps anyone else!